# Нужно ли закрывать соединение с базой в блоке finally?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, ХешКод, у меня вопрос, я написал такой код

```
private void GetSettings()
{
    using (MySqlConnection cnt = new MySqlConnection(sql.strProvider))
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = cnt.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_settings";
        try
        {
            cnt.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                variable.wmrAdmin = reader["WMR"].ToString();
                variable.datastart = reader["STARTDATE"].ToString();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ee)
        {
            log.WriteError(ee.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Так вот, в этом коде есть блок try... catch, и вот не совсем понятно, стоит ли здесь добавить блок

```
finally
{
    cnt.Close();
}
```

Comment: нет, компилятор это сделает за вас

Answer (score 3):

- *Для `cnt` - не надо, а для `reader` - надо.*
- Если функция `Read()` выбросит исключение, то `reader` не будет закрыт. То есть, `reader.Close()` должно располагаться в блоке `finally`.

Comment: или же обернуть ридер оператором using